# Can someone help me get this script to allow download of my file over https with IE8?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

Here's what I got so far from looking at other answers on SO but still getting the error

> "The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later."

Note: This works on other browsers and on IE8 without https.

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache");
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
    "attachment; filename=" +
    "Application.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Why don't you just use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx instead?

Answer (score 1):

Short of [editing the registry on each browser computer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323308), you need to either

- remove the cache-control header
- start the download using an `href`

Comment: Tried the suggestions in that article, other than registry changes, but still not working.  I have the download launching from href and cache-control:no-store set.  Also tried several other variations as well.

Comment: As per the article linked, you need to remove both `no-store` and `no-cache`

Comment: Quote from article "To work around this problem, use a hypertext reference (HREF) to load the document.

Note This workaround works only if the server uses the "cache-control:no-store" header."  I tried it with and without the cache control set just in case but no dice.

Comment: That line is a bit misleading - it means "this workaround works only where the problem is caused by `cache-control:no-store`"